# dark theme in gnome

Tags: gnome, templates

There is problem with dark themes and inputs ...

When i use dark theme for gnome2 (gtk-2), I have problem in the input, the color of fonts in input always dark or black (for example in an application like gnome-applets) and also input background always black or dark too.

What can i do to solve this problem? Can i set it to don't change input color? or force all program use custom color?